# Get difference from two lists in Python

Tags: python

I have two lists, `l1` and `l2`. I need items from `l1` which are not in `l2`.

```
l1 = [2, 3, 4, 5]
l2 = [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

I want to get only [4,5] - only new values in l1.

```
[i for i in l1 if not i in l2 ]
```

Can I do that without iteration?

Comment: Sounds like premature optimization. Why do you say 'no iteration' if this is fundamentally an iterative problem?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Short answer, yes: `list(set(l1) - set(l2))`, though this will not keep order.

Long answer, no, since internally the CPU will always iterate. Though if you use `set()` that iteration will be done highly optimized and will be much faster then your list comprehension (not to mention that checking for membership `value in list` is **much** faster with sets then lists).

Comment: Someone told me that inline iteration is highly optimized as well. And its different from what it perfor when there is: for i in l1: do()

Comment: List comprehensions (not inline iteration) are indeed more optimized than a for loop, but set difference is probably done in high speed C which will be even better. And because you are using sets the `in` keyword (or it's C cousin) is blazing fast thus increasing speed even more.

Answer (score 13):

You can't do it without iteration. Even if you call a single method, internally that will iterate.

Your approach is fine for a small list, but you could use this approach instead for larger lists:

```
s2 = set(l2)
result = [i for i in l1 if not i in s2 ]
```

This will be fast and will also preserve the original order of the elements in l1.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't care about the order of the elements, you can use sets:

```
l1 = set([2, 3, 4, 5])
l2 = set([0, 1, 2, 3])
print l1 - l2
```

prints

```
set([4, 5])
```

Comment: Yep.. I was trying doing something similar. I did not wark for me. Now it's ok. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The conversion to sets is great when your list elements can be converted to sets. Otherwise you'll need something like [Mark Byers' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305164/get-difference-from-two-lists-in-python/5305214#5305214). If you have large lists to compare you might not want to pay the memory allocation overhead and simplify his line to:

```
[l1.remove(m) for m in l1 if m in l2]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Maybe you should reconsider your answer, because the OP seems to want an iteration-free solution. I guess he means no for-loop even not as a list-comprehension. So maybe a map or filter solution would be more appropriate. Also i don't think he wants to alter the original list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use use set_1.difference_update(set_2) for in place difference:

```
>>sl1 = set([2, 3, 4, 5])
>>sl2 = set([0, 1, 2, 3])
>>sl1.difference_update(sl2)
>>sl1
set([4, 5])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this simply as follows:

```
list( set(l1) - set(l2) )
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Convert them to sets and use the difference operator:

```
l1=[2,3,4,5]
l2=[0,1,2,3]

answer = set(l1) - set(l2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the built-in module **[set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set)**

```
>>> a = set([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> b = set([1,3,5])
>>> a.difference(b)
set([2, 4])
```

Another approach

```
>>> a = set([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> b = [1,3,5]
>>> a.difference(b)
set([2, 4])
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply as it is programming, a simple task can be done in a variety of ways.
We can use list comprehension methods like this for exactly the same problem

```
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry", "kiwi", "mango"]
ddd = ["apple", "banana", "mango"]

newlist = [x for x in fruits if x not in ddd]

print(newlist)
```

Answer (score -1):

Example:

```
>>a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
>>b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
```

We can concatenate as well to get the complete difference:

```
>>list (set(a) -set(b)) +  list (set(b) -set(a))
>>[89, 34, 21, 55, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```