# Most pythonic means to find out if an element from one list is not a member of another list

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get difference from 2 lists. Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305164/get-difference-from-2-lists-python)

I have two lists

```
rt = [1,2,3]
dp = [1,2]
```

What is the most pythonic way to find out that in the `rt` list that `3` is not a element of the `dp` list?

Comment: -1 Until you make this clearer

Comment: The answer depends on whether the elements are hashable/sortable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> rt = [1,2,3]
>>> dp = [1,2]
```

You can use sets:

```
>>> set(rt) - set(dp)
set([3])
```

Or a list comprehension:

```
>>> [x for x in rt if x not in dp]
>>> [3]
```

EDIT: jamylak pointed out you could use a set to improve the efficiency of membership lookup:

```
>>> dp_set = set(dp)
>>> [x for x in rt if x not in dp_set]
>>> [3]
```

Comment: To be most efficient you could make `dp_set = set(dp)` and check for membership out of that in your list comp.

Comment: It works on both strings and numbers.  I used the list comprehension.

Comment: @Tampa:  Just keep jamylak's suggestion in mind if efficiently is important to you.

Comment: Well..I liked that too of jamylak.  That solution is now in my toolkit.

Answer (score 3):

If they are both sets you can do this:

```
set(rt) - set(dp)
```

Answer (score 3):

Any of these will work:

```
set(rt).difference(set(dp))
```

OR

```
[i for i in rt if i not in dp]
```

OR

```
set(rt) - set(dp)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for one of these:

```
>>> rt = [1,2,3]
>>> dp = [1,2]
>>> set(rt).issubset(dp)
False
>>> 3 in dp
False
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you may want set subtraction:

```
>>> rt = [1,2,3]
>>> dp = [1,2]
>>> set(rt) - set(dp)
set([3])
```

Answer (score 0):

Kind of ambiguous what you want. You mean you want to check each element of rt against dp?

```
for num in rt:
    if num in dp:
        print(num, 'is in dp!')
    else:
        print(num, 'is not in dp!')
```