# Remove list from list in Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [Get difference from two lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305164/get-difference-from-2-lists-python)

What is a simplified way of doing this? I have been trying on my own, and I can't figure it out. 
list a and list b, the new list should have items that are only in list a. So:

```
a = apple, carrot, lemon
b = pineapple, apple, tomato
new_list = carrot, lemon
```

I tried writing code, but every time it always returns the whole list a to me.

Answer (score 79):

You can write this using a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) which tells us quite literally which elements need to end up in `new_list`:

```
a = ['apple', 'carrot', 'lemon']
b = ['pineapple', 'apple', 'tomato']

# This gives us: new_list = ['carrot' , 'lemon']
new_list = [fruit for fruit in a if fruit not in b]
```

Or, using a for loop:

```
new_list = []
for fruit in a:
    if fruit not in b:
        new_list.append(fruit)
```

As you can see these approaches are quite similar which is why Python also has list comprehensions to easily construct lists.

Comment: Note that this removes all occurrences of elements in `b` in `a`. So if `a == [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4]` and `b == [1, 3]`, then `new_list == [2, 4]`, instead of e.g. `new_list == [1, 1, 2, 4]`.

Answer (score 42):

You can use a [set](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set):

```
# Assume a, b are Python lists

# Create sets of a,b
setA = set(a)
setB = set(b)

# Get new set with elements that are only in a but not in b
onlyInA = setA.difference(b)
```

**UPDATE**
As iurisilvio and mgilson pointed out, this approach only works if `a` and `b` do not contain duplicates, and if the order of the elements does not matter.

Comment: I guess this is the way to go, but it changes the list if it has duplicated strings.

Comment: @iurisilvio: You are right. This approach works only if `a` and `b` only contain unique entries. In that case it would make even more sense to use a `set` for `a`,`b` anyways. But then this is probably the fastest approach.

Comment: It also doesn't work if the order of the items matters, but that might not be the case here (+1 from me)

Comment: I think that the conversion of `b` to a `set` is not necessary. You can also perform the difference using the original `list`.

Comment: @rlar is correct, I found the same to be true.

Answer (score 13):

You may want this:

```
a = ["apple", "carrot", "lemon"]
b = ["pineapple", "apple", "tomato"]

new_list = [x for x in a if (x not in b)]

print new_list
```

Answer (score 8):

Would this work for you?

```python
a = ["apple", "carrot", "lemon"]
b = ["pineapple", "apple", "tomato"]

new_list = []
for v in a:
    if v not in b:
        new_list.append(v)

print new_list
```

Or, more concisely:

```python
new_list = filter(lambda v: v not in b, a)
```

Comment: Most concise and pythonic version so far. Good job!

Comment: It should be noted that in the _more concisely_ example, `new_list` is **not** a list.  It's a filter iterator.

Answer (score 5):

How about using [sets](http://docs.python.org/library/sets.html#module-sets) (or the built in [`set`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set) since Sets was deprecated in 2.6)?

```
from sets import Set
a = Set(['apple', 'carrot', 'lemon'])
b = Set(['pineapple','apple','tomato'])
new_set =  a.difference(b)
print new_set
```

gives the output

```
Set(['carrot', 'lemon'])
```

Comment: Why not use the builtin `set`?

Comment: I got that from the example in the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/sets.html#sets.Set) but i'm not sure why they did it that way, any ideas?

Comment: `sets` is deprecated since Python v2.6 (see http://docs.python.org/library/sets.html)

Comment: I think the `sets` module was around before the builtin `set`.  Now it's mostly left in there for backwards compatability.