# Remove similar numbers in a list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

How do I remove numbers like 86.1 and 90.1 (or 86.2 and 90.2) from the following list?

```
86.1      86.2       90.1      90.2
```

Comment: Can't understand what you asking?

Comment: Define a tolerance value as `tolerance = 3`, Now divide each element with this value and again multiply with the same now use `set` to get the desired results

Comment: How do you define similar? Which one will be removed if two are similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a threshold, iterate over the sorted numbers and add up the numbers within the threshold:

```
numbers = [86.1, 86.2, 90.1,90.2]

threshold = 1
numbers = iter(numbers)
amount = last = next(numbers)
count = 1
result = []
for number in sorted(numbers):
    if number - last > threshold:
        result.append(amount/count)
        amount = count = 0
    amount += number
    count += 1
    last = number
```

result.append(amount/count)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
base = [86.1, 86.2, 90.1, 90.2]
# remove = [86.2, 90.2]
remove = [86.1, 90.1]

new_list = [item for item in base if item not in remove]
print(new_list)
```

In Stack Overflow post *[Remove list from list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434599/remove-list-from-list-in-python)* you have more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
inputList=[86.1, 86.2, 90.1, 90.2]

tolerance=1.0
out=[]
for num in inputList:
    if all([abs(num-outAlready)>tolerance for outAlready in out]):
        out.append(num)

print out
```